# xmm register sse x64 value inside

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, sse

I'm writing project to shool in x64 assembly. I'm using nasm compilator. I know that xmm registers can store 4 x 32 bit or 2x64 bit. I wandered to know how i can put 4 float values (32 bit) into xmm1 for example. My function has header `curve(float * x, float * y, int a, int b)` and x is pointer to 5 element array. I was looking for some information but I still don't know how to do it properly.
Thanks for help in advance!
(ps. if you have any tutorials including informations about sse it will be very helpful)

Comment: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse_load.htm#intref_sse_load

Comment: this project is full in assembly - I mean that I have to do this function definition in assembly only.

Comment: Then your best bet is to compile from C code and look at how the compiler does it. In short, it isn't trivial - at least to be efficient, it's not trivial. (Though I warn that VC++ can generate pretty stupid code for these set intrinsics.)

Comment: I know it's not trivial and that's why I've asked. And I also know it's very efficient and that's reason why i want to learn about it... Maybe some tutorial or something like this...?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you find that (un)packing data is a bottleneck, then you should probably change the memory layout make vector operations more "vertical".

Comment: All I have to do is compute coordinates of points on Bezier curve. This arrays include coordignates of 5 control points wchich tolds about shape of this curve. Pattern I'm using include X coordignate of every control point. Every coordignate is muliplied by different value. So I can make 2 mulipies (points 1-4 and point 5) instead of 5 implies. And that is why I'm so interesting in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the movdqa, movdqu, movaps, movups, movapd, movupd instructions to load values into a 128bit SSE register (xmm) from memory.  The movdqa, movaps, movapd require 16-byte aligned memory access (and are faster).

Incidentally, doing one point at a time with SIMD would require a lot of code changes.  Better bet is to do 4 at a time (because SIMD has 4 lanes of single precision floating point).  Then you can (more or less) just replace each regular instruction with the same vector instruction.